# jquery bootgrid issue with requestHandler / post reload

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I'm trying to pass other values (as a filters) to a  jquery bootgrid. In my form I have two date range and I need to refresh grid data every time dates change.

Handler *requestHandler* and (obsolete) *post* allow me to pass to a server other params respect the standard

But when I post my request I'm not able to add my custom parameters. With firebug I can see only standard parameters likes

```
current=1
rowCount=10
searchPhrase=
```

Please help me!!

Below my complete HTML code

```
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" data-toggle="bootgrid" data-ajax="true" data-url="HelpDesk/server.php">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th data-column-id="ticket_no" data-type="string" data-identifier="true">ticket_no</th>
                        <th data-column-id="title">title</th>
                                                <th data-column-id="parent_id" data-type="string">parent_id</th>
                        <th data-column-id="contact_id" data-type="string">contact_id</th>
                        <th data-column-id="status">status</th>
                        <th data-column-id="priority" data-type="string">priority</th>
                                                <th data-column-id="smownerid" data-type="string">smownerid</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                </table>
```

and my js/jquery code

```
<!-- now write the script specific for this grid -->
<script language="javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {   

    var grid = $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        url: "HelpDesk/server.php",
        //requestHandler    
        //Transforms the JSON request object in what ever is needed on the server-side implementation.
        // Default value is function (request) { return request; }.
        requestHandler: function(request)
        {
            console.log("requestHandler - nevel called");
            console.log(request);
            return request;     
        }/*,
        post: function () 
        {  
            console.log("post - nevel called"); 
            return {datefrom:'aaaaaaaaa',dateto:'vvvvvvvvvv'}; 
        }*/
    });

    $('input[name="srch"]').click(function(){

        $("#grid-data").bootgrid("reload");
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To pass some additional information to your server you just need to add these parameters to the `request` object and return it. For example:

```
requestHandler: function (request) {
    request.myParam1 = "test";
    request.oneMoreMyParam = "test again";
    return request;
}
```

And on the server side you will receive something like this:

```
current = 1, 
rowCount = 15,
searchPhrase = "",
myParam1 = "test",
oneMoreMyParam = "test again"
```

But you wrote that your `requestHandler` was never been called, right? It is strange. It must be called on the `"reload"` event. I use this function too. Also I don't write properties of the `<table>` like `data-ajax="true" data-url="..."` and use:

```
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        requestHandler: function (request) {
            request.myParam= $("#some-input").val();
            return request;
        },
        url: "..."
    });

    $("#some-button").on("click", function () {         
        $("#grid-data").bootgrid("reload");
    });
</script>
```

And everything works good.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came here looking for an answer. Check if you have `data-toggle="bootgrid"` set on table element. This seems to be overriding the manual bootgrid initializing from js file. Removing that did the trick for me. Hope this helps.